# Behat - Step definition for date? Today and -/+ days?

Tags: php, drupal, behat

Wonder if someone can help me, I am using Behat to automate testing of a drupal site..

I am wanting to input a date in the format - dd/mm/YYYY - I can manually enter this, but a variable of a form is for a date over 30 days.

Is there a way in Behat (I can't find one) that I can call that will put todays date in a field, and also todays date + or - X number of days? It doesn't seem like this is built in, but I

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get this working...add this to your FormContext file -

```
/**
 * Fills in specified field with date
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "now"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-7 days"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "+7 days"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 weeks"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 years"
 *
 * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with date "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function fillDateField($field, $value)
{
    $newDate = strtotime("$value");

    $dateToSet = date("d/m/Y", $newDate);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($field, $dateToSet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to @Karl's response-- his uses a particular date format, I extended it to add a configurable date format. I kept both step definitions (one with a default format, one with configurable format)

```
 /**
   * Fills in specified field with date
   * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "now" in the format "m/d/Y"
   * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-7 days" in the format "m/d/Y"
   * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "+7 days" in the format "m/d/Y"
   * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 weeks" in the format "m/d/Y"
   * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 years" in the format "m/d/Y"
   *
   * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with date "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" in the format "(?P<format>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
   */
  public function fillDateFieldFormat($field, $value, $format)
  {
    $newDate = strtotime("$value");

    $dateToSet = date($format, $newDate);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($field, $dateToSet);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your field has an `id` attribute, you can use step definition below.

`<input id="from_date" ....../>`

`And I fill in "from_date" with "02/03/2016"`

If you run `$ bin/behat -dl`, you'll see all the built-in steps.

Cheatsheet: http://blog.lepine.pro/images/2012-03-behat-cheat-sheet-en.pdf

Comment: Hey, yeah I get that I can put a manual date, but I want the script to be able to put "todays date" when the script runs, and "todays date +/- days" when the script runs, if i set a date now, and run it in a months time, that date will be a month out of date, and my tests will not perform correctly..

Comment: Create a new step definition in FeatureContext file to do that for you. You have a lot of examples here: www.inanzzz.com

Comment: ah ok, I have had a look on there, and can't work out how to do it, I guess I want to use the "$today = date("m.d.y"); " php command, but I can't work out how to use it in a step definition, and there doesn't seem to be an example close enough on that site for me to modify to work it out..